# How not to trigger RequiredFieldValidator on hidden field (TextBox)

Tags: asp.net, validation

I think this is a common problem. I have a form where I show/hide fields dynamically using jQuery, depending on some radio buttons.

I have RequiredFieldValidator's on all the fields, but I don't want them to be triggered if their ControlToValidate is hidden (using jQuery).

Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Here is the solution**, thanks to Marek. It might not be very obvious if you have weird clientIDs because of MasterPages

This is the ASPX

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldName" ControlToValidate="txtName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must enter Name!" />
...
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

This is the jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('#ctl00_cphContent_btnSubmit').click(function() {
    if (!$('#ctl00_cphContent_txtName').is(':visible'))
      ValidatorEnable(ctl00_cphContent_vldName, false);
  });
});
```

Hope it will make someone's life easier

Comment: Quick tip, never hardcode the IDs of controls in javascript, use $('#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').click... instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly there's a function called `ValidatorEnable(validatorClientId, isEnabled)` that allows you to disable/enable the ASP.NET validators via javascript.  You could use jQuery right before your form submit to disable all your invisible validators.

There's some documentation about client side API available from the validators here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx

Comment: That's a link to a vintage 2000 document, updated in 2002, so .NET 1.0? With mention of HTML 3.2, haven't thought about that in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Hey u can set the control to validate property from C# code when u r setting visiblility from C# code.This wil solves ur problem.

```
if ($('#input-name').length) {  
       // do something

}
```

This will now solves ur problem

Comment: The problem is I do things using jQuery to avoid unnecessary postbacks and delays. No C# involved.

Comment: Aximili - If u are using jQuery then I am sure that there is no need of such control named RequiredFieldValidator beacuase it is a ASP.net control.  Moreover in jQuery u can write code to first check whether that control exists.

Comment: You're right, I am currently writing my own validators. I was just wondering if I can still use ASP.NET validators because it will mean writing less code for me.