# Only enable RequiredFieldValidator when parent element is visible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, validation

I have an asp.net webform with a few Panels that each have several textboxes inside of it.  I am currently hiding or displaying the panel using jQuery based on which item in a DropDownList is selected.

I have run into an issue where the required field validator is still firing even when the elements it is attached to is not showing because it's parent panel has `display: none`.

Is there any way to disable the RequiredFieldValidator when the element it is attached to is not showing because of CSS?

I know that if set Visible=false on the server side the elements wouldn't render at all, but I would prefer to keep the show/hide logic on the client side for user experience reasons.

Comment: You would have to implement this functionality using a custom validator.

Comment: I'd enter your comment as an answer Ben; I agree that there's no way to do what Abe wants short of a custom validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that a custom validator would be best, but if you do need to do it on the client side, you can use the ValidatorEnable function.

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("<%= RequiredFieldValidator.ClientID %>"), false);
```

(Note that I have never actually tried this myself, but I have heard of it successfully being used to disable validators on the client side.)

Answer (score 1):

As [this thread says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710342/how-not-to-trigger-requiredfieldvalidator-on-hidden-field-textbox), you can use that function. So modify your method like below

```
    function cbSearchOption_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
    var x = document.getElementById('cbSearchOption').value
    if (x == 'Date')
    {
        ValidatorEnable($get(‘<%=DateValidator1.ClientID %>’), true);
        document.getElementById('test').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else
    {
        ValidatorEnable($get(‘<%=DateValidator1.ClientID %>’), false);
        document.getElementById('test').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```