# Dropdown list textbox required field validator error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a dropdown list for the which values are coming from DB. There is one option name OTHER, when I select other the textbox appears. For that Textbox I have made a required field validator. Till here it works fine. But when I select any other option, still it gives me validator errors. It should not happen. It should only give me required field error when the user doesn't fills the textbox on select of OTHER option. Please see the code.

Dropdown and Textbox code:-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGraduation" runat="server" CssClass="txtfld-popup_drp"></asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="error_msg" ID="reqGraduation" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlGraduation" ErrorMessage="Please select graduation details" InitialValue="--Select--" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>



<asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server" CssClass="txtfld-popup_p"></asp:TextBox>                                                                                


<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqOther" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtOther" ErrorMessage="Please specify your qualification"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

JS code for hiding and show the textbox when user select and deselect the OTHER option from dropdown list:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').hide();
        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlGraduation').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === "Other") {
                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').show();
                // $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlGraduation").hide();
            } else {
                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should disable the RequiredFieldValidator for the hidden control. Possible duplicate of [How not to trigger RequiredFieldValidator on hidden field (TextBox)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710342/how-not-to-trigger-requiredfieldvalidator-on-hidden-field-textbox)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable your required field validator only when your textbox is visible, you need to write below line of code in your javascriot function when you are showing your textbox:

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("reqGraduation"), true);
```

Your javascript code shuld be like this:

```
function pageLoad() {
        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').hide();
        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlGraduation').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === "Other") {
                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').show();

               ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("reqGraduation"), true); 
                // $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlGraduation").hide();
            } else {
                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOther').hide();

                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("reqGraduation"), false); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where should I write ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("reqGraduation"), true); ??

is it in javascript page load function ?

Comment: in Javascript  at client side..I have modified your javascriopt function please chk

Comment: can you give me a js fiddle, as my hidden textbox code is also not working. Please . I tried, I think your code can match my requirement. Just need a JS fiddle

Comment: its not working, it still giving me validation error, "Please specify your qualification." please see my js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/257mc/